# Vertical line on x axis on midnight in HighCharts/HighStock

Tags: highcharts

We are using HighStock/HighCharts and have a datetime x axis. The data set contains multiple points for each hour, and we are using default tick settings.
However, we are attempting to add a vertical grid line for each midnight point. If we set gridLineWidth > 0 on the x axis, we get a vertical line for each tick, which is not our intention.

One solution could be to add plotlines for each day at midnight in our data set - but are there another/better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

The most convenient method to add the lines seems to be creating them programmatically with using `Highcharts.SVGRenderer` class.

```
    chart: {
        events: {
            load: function() {
                var xAxis = this.xAxis[0],
                    startDate = new Date(xAxis.dataMin),
                    firstMidnight = new Date(startDate.getDate() + '-' +
                        startDate.getMonth() + '-' +
                        startDate.getFullYear()).getTime(),
                    x,
                    y1 = this.plotTop,
                    y2 = y1 + this.plotHeight;

                firstMidnight -= startDate.getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000;

                for (
                    var i = firstMidnight; i < new Date(xAxis.dataMax).getTime(); i += 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
                ) {
                    x = xAxis.toPixels(i);

                    if (x > this.plotLeft) {
                        this.renderer.path(['M', x, y1, 'L', x, y2])
                            .attr({
                                'stroke-width': 1,
                                stroke: 'red'
                            })
                            .add()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/us1an6jk/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#path

Comment: Brilliant but we need to fix the getMonth() issue...
change startDate.getMonth() in (1+startDate.getMonth()) othewise the date will be 1 moth shifted in the past.

Comment: In addition date in firstMidnight must be in YYYY-MM-DD format hence the final code would be: 
firstMidnight = new Date(startDate.getFullYear()+ '-' +(1+startDate.getMonth())+ '-'+startDate.getDate()).getTime(),....